# QGIS delimited text data not updating bearing lines

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I have 3 delimited text layers which are loading lat long data directly from an excel sheet and the corresponding points are automatically updated in my project map the moment I save the Excel sheet.

In addition to that, I want to create bearing lines from those points for which I am using "Shape Tools" plugin which is taking azimuth data from the same Excel sheet.

While the lat long data is getting updated, the bearing lines are not getting changed. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: What does the Shape Tools plugin do?

Answer (score 3):

I am not very familiar with the Shape Tools plug-in, but its description at https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/shapetools/ uses language which suggests it takes layers *at a certain point in time* and processes them to generate other layers with richer information. This type of approach will not update automatically when you change the data in the underlying layer.

The good news is that you can make many things in QGIS update dynamically if you implement them using inherently dynamic techniques, rather than using the processing/create new layer paradigm. To do so, use the following.

1. Make sure your delimited text layer(s) have **`Watch file`** turned on. It seems you have done this.
2. Define calculations (e.g. in your case azimuths, distances, angles) as **virtual fields** (`Layer properties / Fields` then field calculator icon, create new field with virtual field turned on. You can use the very rich QGIS expression language to calculate what you need, and as a virtual field the attributes you are thus creating are recalculated by QGIS whenever the underlying data changes.
3. Optionally use the **geometry generator** symbol layer type in the layer symbology to make use of these calculations (from virtual fields, or more complicated ad-hoc QGIS expressions) to display this calculated data. Alternatively, you might be able to merely use **data-driven overrides** for some of the parameters of other symbol layer types.

As an example, in one project I have a virtual field `"Azimuth`" that calculates the angle line of sight from points in a CSV layer to a desired point, using a QGIS `azimuth($geometry,make_point(@target_x,@target_y))` expression (in this case with layer variables `@target_x,y`). I then have a simple line marker layer in the symbology whose rotation is a data-driven override using this `"Azimuth"`.